# passing argument to dplyr slice

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use slice to get the maximum value and the position (to get the date) over a large data.frame and I want to do  it for several variables. So , I am writing a custom function to pass several variables as argument, but it's not working.

```
           mvar <- "WD"
          
           peak_max <- dataf%>%group_by(year=format(date,"%Y"))%>%
                   dplyr::slice(which.max(!!mvar))
```

I used summarise, but it also failed when passing the argument:

```
            peak_max <- dataf%>%group_by(year=format(date,"%Y"))%>%
                    dplyr::summarise(date=date[which.max(!!mvar)], wd=max(!!mvar))
```

I also tried with   mvar <-  enquo(mvar) , but it doesn't work. What am I missing?
Both worked when using WD directly, instead !!mvar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We could use `!!sym(mvar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your using an older approach to [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). `Enquo()` and `!!` aren't used anymore.

It's hard to be sure what you want to achieve without your data, but, if you pass the variable directly (as you do in `dplyr` pipes, you can embrace it `{{ var }}` in a function. If you're passing a string name for the variable, you need you use `.data[[var]]`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# pass variable directly
my_func_var <- function(df, var){
  df %>% slice_max({{ var }})
}

iris %>% my_func_var(Sepal.Length)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1          7.9         3.8          6.4           2 virginica

# pass variable as string
my_func_str <- function(df, var){
  df %>% slice_max(.data[[var]])
}

my_var <- "Sepal.Length"
iris %>% my_func_str(my_var)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#> 1          7.9         3.8          6.4           2 virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

(I used `slice_max()` as it felt more natural, but `which.max()` seems to work too)